# Chaplin router optional parameters

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing, chaplinjs

I am working on ChaplinJS (backbone framework). 
Following is my route.js code block.

```
return function(match) {        
    match(':customer/getCardsNavSummary', {controller:'customer', action:'showPlan'});
    match(':customer/getCardsNavSummary/:plan/:row', {controller:'customer', action:'showPlan'});
};
```

Instead, I want to do the following

```
return function(match) {
        match(':customer/getCardsNavSummary(/:plan/:row)', {controller:'customer', action:'showPlan'});
    };
```

This works well foe Backbone. I went through the routing code for rails also, and there it works. But when it comes to chaplinjs it don't !

In chaplinJS doc i did not find any thing related to router optional parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Chaplin.Router` does not extend `Backbone.Router`. As far as i know, what you trying to achieve is not possible with the `Chaplin.Router`.

As your desired endpoint is the same for both routes (customer:showPlan), one possible workaround is to use the [constraints option](http://docs.chaplinjs.org/chaplin.router.html) with a regexp that matches both *getCardsNavSummary* and *getCardsNavSummary-plan-row* pattern and then, in the Controller, check and parse this endpoint as needed.

Comment: OK; Thanks. I have raised this issues.
https://github.com/chaplinjs/chaplin/issues/641#issue